# How to properly use has_many to build a hierarchy in json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want to display json as a hierarchical model, but something I'm doing wrong ...

Who can explain what I did wrong?

I have the following "Serializers":

```
class ManagementSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :managmentstructure_id, :users_id, :full_name, :users_id_parent, :managements

  def managements
    object.managments.map do |managment|
      ManagementSerializer.new(management, root: false)
    end
  end
end
```

and "Controller":

```
def index
  @managments = Managment.all

  render json: @managments
end
```

What I'm getting is:

## 1

```
{
    "managmentstructure_id": 1,
    "users_id": 32,
    "full_name": "Test",
    "users_id_parent": null
    "managments": [
      {
        "managmentstructure_id": 2,
        "users_id": 43,
        "full_name": "Test2",
        "users_id_parent": 32
        "managments": [
          {
            "managmentstructure_id": 3,
            "users_id": 58,
            "full_name": "Test3",
            "users_id_parent": 43
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
},
```

## 2

```
{
  "managmentstructure_id": 2,
  "users_id": 43,
  "full_name": "Test2",
  "users_id_parent": 32
  "managments": [
          {
            "managmentstructure_id": 3,
            "users_id": 58,
            "full_name": "Test3",
            "users_id_parent": 43
          }
   ]
 },
{
  "managmentstructure_id": 3,
  "users_id": 58,
  "full_name": "Test3",
  "users_id_parent": 43
  "managments": []
 }
```

my model:

```
class Managment < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'PROJECT.V_L_MANAGMENTSTRUCTURES'
  self.primary_key = 'users_id'

  has_many :managments, class_name: 'Managment',
  foreign_key: "users_id_parent"
  belongs_to :managment, class_name: 'Managment'
end
```

Or is it not possible to do this with the help of "Serializers"?

Comment: Are you sure the response you're expecting is what you want ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna For me the main thing is that it was in a hierarchical form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, this is how I would keep it.

```
class ManagementSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :managements
  attributes :managmentstructure_id, :users_id, :full_name, :users_id_parent, managements

  def managements
    object.managments.map do |managment|
      ManagementSerializer.new(management, root: false).serializable_hash        
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The hierarchy has turned out, but there is one thing, some records are duplicated and displayed below as a separate element

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you update your question with the `response` you're seeing

Comment: I updated the question "What I get is this:"  there is a duplicate creation of records from the hierarchy

Comment: Do you have duplicate records in your db ?

Comment: no, I do not have duplicates in the database, at least in this table

Comment: From _you're updated response_, which part do you see as duplicated ? I think the way you have associated has led to that response, I don't see any **duplicates** in the response.

Comment: In the Sense do not see, pay attention to the question on the 1 and 2 record. The first part is printed correctly, and the second part is added from the first and outputs as a duplicate is obtained (they have the same id)

Comment: it did not help me, returned to its original form(

Comment: Let's continue the discussion [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179786/activerecordserializer)

Comment: I apologize, but I do not have enough reputation to communicate there, and yes, I tried the new answer the result is the same as the question

Comment: Can you share your `associations` and `models` ?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: Ok, that's weird, so in your response, you're expecting a `json` object which contains all `managements` ? What are `managmentstructure_id`,  `users_id`. How are you fetching them ?

Comment: Yes, and what's strange?, as I could still do if the link is installed inside one table

Comment: "Managmentstructure_id" is like a primary key, users_id is the key that is associated with the user table (I just forgot to add a link to the model)

Comment: I'm trying to understand how is `managementstructure_id` and `management` related and same with user ? If they are just columns in one table what is point of breaking them up in the response ?

Comment: `managementstructure_id` is the primary key for `management` table ? if that's the case, they are the same. In the response, you cannot expect { managementstructure_id: managements: [] }. If you want such a response, you should have something like `management_structure` and `management` as two tables and build association between them and you can do `management_structure.managements` for `has_many`.

Comment: As per your current association, all you can do is get all the management, just by doing `object.managements`. That's the only possibility I see for now.